# Power Query: Perform Applied Steps for a Column Only if it Exists, Avoid Error if it Doesn't Exist

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I am using Power Query in Excel for Microsoft 365.

Please consider the following M Language code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type of all to Text" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"A", type text}, {"B", type text}, {"C", type text}}),
    #"Removed Unneeded Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type of all to Text",{"A"}),
    ...
in
    #"Removed Duplicate Rows"
```

The problem I'm running into is that column **A** is not always present in the source table. If it is present, it must be removed. However, including it in the M Language code induces an error in instances when it is not present.

How may I change my M Language code to effectively handle both the case of column **A** being present and the case of column **A** not being present?

Comment: Try selecting the columns you do want and then apply `Remove Other Columns`.

Comment: You could use `try...otherwise`; you could use `Table.ColumnNames(#"Previous Step")`; remove Column **`A`** from the list if it exists; then use `Table.SelectColumns` referencing that list. And I'm sure there are other methods also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Restatement of the Original Problem

> The problem I'm running into is that column **A** is not always present in
> the source table. If it is present, it must be removed. However,
> including it in the M Language code induces an error in instances when
> it is not present.

### The Solution

As a preliminary, I'll note that when I first create the query by right-clicking on a cell in my source table and by then selecting `Get Data from Table/Range...`, two applied steps are automatically created:

1. Source
2. Changed Type

The solution to my problem is as follows:

1. Insert a `Choose Columns` applied step between the `Source` and `Changed Type` applied steps and de-select column **A** *if it is present* (I may or may not be working with an instance of the source table that has column **A** in it)
2. Edit the M Language code of the `Changed Type` applied step to remove the parameter corresponding to column **A** *if it is present* (I may or may not be working with an instance of the source table that has column **A** in it)

The key is to **not reference** column **A** in the M Language code (because an error will be thrown if it is referenced but is not present). So, rather than explicitly select column **A** for removal, just don't select it for inclusion.

Structuring the query this way allows it to be applied to source tables that either do or do not contain column **A**. It will work in both cases.